# VHDL procedure evaluation and call sequence

Tags: vhdl

I want to ask what is the order of procedure call in VHDL.

Below I have VHDL code showing a procedure called 'IncrementWrap' and a process which calls the procedure multiple times.

I got the code form a Youtube video and of course have not run it myself, but will this code even execute?

When the Tick value is = clock_frequency-1 just before the rising edge, the tick value gets reset back to 0 as shown by the procedure. But what about the conditional check beneath it? Will that also be evaluated? And the procedure 'IncrementWrap' called but for seconds?

Is the procedure and the conditional check beneath it evaluated in parallel?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are not aware of when a `signal` is updated inside a clocked process in VHDL.

In your code, the procedure `IncrementWrap ()` will execute and update the respective signals if the preceding condition is true, and the update is not 'immediate'. The signals are updated after a [delta delay](https://www.ece.ucdavis.edu/%7Evojin/CLASSES/EEC180B/Spring99/simulation.pdf) by the simulator, i.e., the signals are *scheduled* to be updated only at the end of the execution of `process (Clk)` at the rising edge of `Clk`.

> When the Tick value is = clock_frequency-1 just before the rising edge, the tick value gets reset back to 0 as shown by the procedure. But what about the conditional check beneath it?

Since the `if` condition goes true at the rising edge of `Clk`, `Ticks` is *scheduled* to be updated to 0 by the `IncrementWrap()` **only** at the end of `process (Clk)` execution. Hence, `Ticks` would still be `ClockFrequencyHz-1` for the below statements to evaluate, for the current rising edge of `Clk`.

Answer (score 0):

The effect of a sequential signal assignment in VHDL is not visible until the process ends. Procedures are irrelevant to this rule and behave as any other code in a process (the end of a procedure does not make any sequential effects become visible).

So, yes, your conditional will be hit even though the preceding procedure call sets the variable to 0.

Comment: Until the process ends, or reaches a "wait".